# Delete partial duplicates from a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this

```
Id  FirstName
5   Adam
6   Bob
8   Bob
5   Carl
5   Dewie
8   Ernest
```

When two rows have the same Id, I'd like to keep only one of them. On this example, I would obtain

```
Id  FirstName
5   Adam
6   Bob
8   Bob
```

Is there concise command to that? I was thinking of

```
SELECT * FROM Persons HAVING(COUNT(Id)=1)
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Id), FirstName FROM Persons
```

but my syntax isn't correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope you are looking for this::

```
SELECT * from Persons GROUP BY Id
```

Comment: Thank you, that question was simple

Comment: @SashiKant, This will give him an error, since `FirstName` isn't in the `GROUP BY` clause nor in an aggregated funciton

Comment: @Mahmoud actually Sashi's query does work in MySQL, but not in MSSQL. See here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ee84/1

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Id, MIN(FirstName)
FROM Persons
GROUP By Id
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `DISTINCT` query will also work, you just need to add `GROUP BY id`

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Id), FirstName
FROM Persons 
GROUP BY id;
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ee84/4)